# How can I exclude a specific file from git?

Tags: git, repository

I need to exclude dbconfig.php from git repository. How can I remove it from the current indexing in the current repository? Can I exclude it from being added to the repo even when running **git add .**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove the file from the index:

`git rm --cached dbconfig.php`

Then, in the root of the repository, create `.gitignore` and add `dbconfig.php` to it.

`git add .gitignore` and `git commit -m "new gitignore"` and it should go missing the next time you do a `git status` or `add .`

Comment: Where exactly should i run git rm --cached dbconfig.php ? Should it be in the same folder that dbconfig.php is in ?

Comment: You can run it in the root of the project, as long as you specify the path to the file. So you could do `git rm --cached path/to/dbconfig.php` or just change to that directory and run `git rm --cached dbconfig.php`

Answer (score 1):

Add a file named `.gitignore` in the repository and put a line in it:

```
dbconfig.php
```

Then `git add .gitignore` and commit it.

If you already committed the file before, you might want to reset to back before you committed it and re-add the other files, omitting the one you don't want tracked. (Removing it and committing again would remove it from tracking, but the history would still be there - assuming the file contains sensitive data, you wouldn't want that.)

http://help.github.com/ignore-files/